# Android copying sqlite database via MTP mode

Tags: android, sqlite, mtp

I have strange problem. It is on `LG E440` (bought yesterday). We have warehouse inventory app for android. Data is stored in `SQLite` database. After copying database file from phone to computer sometime i get error when reading `sqlite` database: `database disk image is malformed`. Until now we have only samsung galaxy s2 two years without problems (i always connected usb in mass storage mode). I read this [Flush MTP connection with Android tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115481/flush-mtp-connection-with-android-tablet). After that i connected LG phone again to computer and copied again database files and I can read in windows database file without problems. How I can avoid theses problems with MTP caching? And problem is windows or android ? Also look at this video: http://youtu.be/V2z4eGYRLAQ. In windows only I can see file if I rename it in android. Is there a way to enable usb mass storage mode in `LG E440` ?

Comment: Problem is related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737261/nexus-4-not-showing-files-via-mtp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14074407/645495

From here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38282

> All phones using MTP instead of USB Mass storage do not properly show
>   the list of files when that phone is connected to a computer using a
>   USB cable. Android apps running on the device also cannot see these
>   files.
>
> This affects files written using Java APIs, but does not appear to
>   affect files written using the C API.
>
> The solution is to reboot the device.