# SQLite Database malformed after copy&paste from Android to Windows

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the exact same problem as described here:
[Flush MTP connection with Android tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115481/flush-mtp-connection-with-android-tablet)

Every time I add a Column in my Android App in a local SQLite-Database, my Database gets malformed when I copy and paste the file to Windows machine.

It works when I do the following steps:

1. Copy my Database to Android Filesystem
2. Disconnect USB
3. Open my App (Add Column)
4. Connect USB again
5. Copy/Paste Database File from Android to Windows = Not malformed

Or

1. Copy my Database to Android Filesystem
2. Open my App (Add Column)
3. Reboot Android device
4. Copy/Paste Database-File to Windows = Not malformed

Rescan does not help at all. It 2019, is there any solutions for this problem?

Comment: Before copying the file try closing the database or try copying the -shm and -wal files (same name as the database file but suffixed with -shm and -wal).

Comment: I did close my connection to database but that has no effect or maybe I did it wrong. I have no shm or wal files, just a journal file.